# Unsupported class file major version 58

Tags: java, linux, windows

I've been struggling with a lot of JDK versions for like a week or two to get this working:

https://www.rune-server.ee/runescape-development/rs2-server/downloads/696766-kronos-osrs-semi-custom-server-deob-client-multi-world-support-184-a.html

and just limited to giving me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58
```

I have JDK 13, 14, and 16 installed.
Before this, I had been testing and it was giving me these errors:

https://www.rune-server.ee/runescape-development/rs2-server/downloads/696766-kronos-osrs-semi-custom-server-deob-client-multi-world-support-184-a-13.html#post5740612

Answer (score 1):

> I have JDK 13, 14 and 16 installed

This is irrelevant; you must **run** whatever you're trying to run with the right java version; an older java version is not just going to farm out the work to an installed newer one.

v58 requires JDK14 and up. Check which java you are actually running this with. Or just go to your JDK14 or 16 installation, and run `./java -jar whatever.jar`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.
Yes, I have JDK14, but it keeps giving me that error and I have no idea what to do to fix it. In IntelliJ I also choose the JDK14 version, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: When you see that error, __you aren't running on JDK14__. It doesn't matter what you have installed, it matters what you run it with. If you don't know enough about your Operating System to configure it properly, the easiest way to solve this problem is to just uninstall all the JDKs less than 14.

Comment: I uninstalled all of them, in IntelliJ I put JDK14, in the path I put the address of JDK / bin. And none of this worked :(

Comment: The one and only way that error ever appears is if you're running a JDK at version 13 or less. I don't have a crystal ball and can't look at your system configuration, and your question does not explain how you run this stuff. There's no further way to help you out without more details.

Comment: Like "How do you run these things"? I did not understand that. I only have version 14 of jdk installed, it is on the path and in IntelliJ it is set to JDK 14 as well. Could you try to follow the tutorial on the link and see if it really works and tell me how? Maybe that way I can see if it's a problem of mine, or of the code... From now on, thanks

Comment: What you state is simply impossible. Are you clicking 'run' in intellij, are you running `java -jar foo.jar` on the command line, are you double-clicking a jar - that's what 'how do you run it' means.

Comment: 'Could you try to follow the tutorial on the link and see if it really works and tell me how? Maybe that way I can see if it's a problem of mine, or of the code... From now on, thanks'

Comment: @KATalyzt there would be absolutely no point whatsoever in doing that.

Comment: Why? If it seems that only me gives me this problem :(

Comment: This error means what I said it means; it doesn't mean anything else. You are running a JDK14+ compatibility class file on a JDK13 or below java. The problem lies in your system configuration; my system configuration is different, therefore me repeating your steps accomplishes nothing. If I duplicate your system setup, we'd be getting somewhere, but I don't know your system setup.

Comment: I did not say that you replicate my system, only if following the creator's tutorial you could see if it works for you (which it does not work for me).
And I only have JDK14 installed and it doesn't work, I have the path pointing to the JDK14 and in the IntelliJ the JDK14 established ... But no, it doesn't work :/